# how to change the SpriteKit tile group of a tile in a tilemap?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

My goal is to change the color of a tile from grey to green every time the tile is touched. 
The final effects can be seen from the pictures: 
[image]

[image]

The solution I have tried is to 
1. calculate the row and column position of the current tile according to the touch CGPosition

```
func currentTileCalculator (){
        let column = MTileMap.tileColumnIndex(fromPosition: firstTouch)
        let row = MTileMap.tileRowIndex(fromPosition: firstTouch)
        let currentTile = MTileMap.tileDefinition(atColumn: column, row: row)
        print("column: ", column, "row: ", row)
        currentTileTuple.column = column
        currentTileTuple.row = row
    }
```

2. use canColor flag to make sure the touch is inside the letter M, so we don't end up coloring tiles outside the letter M.

```
 func canColorCalculator(){
       var touchedTile = MTileMap.tileDefinition(atColumn: currentTileTuple.column, row: currentTileTuple.row)

       if let _ = currentTouchedTile?.userData?.value(forKey: "grey square"){
           canColor = true
           print("you can color now :)")
       }else{
           print("you cannot color :(")
           canColor = false
       }
   }
```

3. change the currentTile from grey colored tile group to green colored tile group.
   I dont know how to code for this step. 
   I have tried to change the textures of currentTouchedTile but it didn't work.

```
currentTouchedTile?.textures[0] = SKTexture(imageNamed: "greenColor.png")
```

Comment: What is MTileMap?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to your problem?